# Virtual machines can't reach each other through bridge

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I am using the QubesOS operating system, and I am failing to connect virtual machines through a bridge in another VM. The initial config looks like this:

- Router VM:

  ```
  [user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ ip a
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  2: vif12.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 32
      link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.0/32 scope global vif12.0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 scope link 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  3: vif11.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 32
      link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.0/32 scope global vif11.0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 scope link 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  4: vif13.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 32
      link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.0/32 scope global vif13.0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 scope link 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  5: vif14.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 32
      link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.0/32 scope global vif14.0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 scope link 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  [user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ ip r
  192.168.100.1 dev vif12.0 scope link metric 32740 
  192.168.100.2 dev vif11.0 scope link metric 32741 
  192.168.100.3 dev vif13.0 scope link metric 32739 
  192.168.100.4 dev vif14.0 scope link metric 32738
  ```

Also the IPv4 forwarding parameter of sysconf is properly set in the router VM.

- Client VMs:

  ```
  [user@lab-adsis2-box1 ~]$ ip a
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 00:16:3e:5e:6c:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.1/32 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe5e:6c00/64 scope link 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  [user@lab-adsis2-box1 ~]$ ip r
  default via 192.168.100.0 dev eth0 
  192.168.100.0 dev eth0 scope link
  ```

Like this the VMs are able to ping each other, so the router is working. However the problem comes when I try  to set a bridge to unify all the interfaces of the router:

```
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip l a name br0 type bridge
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip link set br0 up
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip link set br0 up
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip l set vif11.0 master br0
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip l set vif12.0 master br0
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip l set vif13.0 master br0
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip l set vif14.0 master br0
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ sudo ip a a dev br0 192.168.100.0/16
[user@lab-adsis2-router ~]$ bridge link
2: vif12.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100 
3: vif11.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100 
4: vif13.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100 
5: vif14.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
```

After doing this I am unable to ping between clients, and I have no idea why.

All machines are Fedora 29 and ebtables is not installed.